# Random Car Color Generator

Tags: java, loops, netbeans

I would like to random generate the name of cars based on the input of the user

I tried using a while loop and do while loop to generate random cars but I was unable to iterate the loop based on the number provided by the user. When the user inputs 4 sometimes it generates 2 or 3 times but doesn't generate 4 times

`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


String[] colors ={"Blue", "Red","Green", "Purple"};
Random r = new Random();

int length;
System.out.println("How many cars would you like to paint?");
length = in.nextInt();
String[] cars = new String[length];

for(int k = 0 ; k < length; k++)
{
    System.out.println ("Enter the name of cars" + (k+1));
    cars[k] = in.next();
}
in.close();
System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");


final Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
final Set<Integer> t = new HashSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
                while(true){
                int car = r.nextInt(cars.length) + 1;
                do{
                if (t.contains(car) == false){
                    t.add(car);
                    System.out.println(cars[car - 1]);
                }
                else{
                    car = r.nextInt(cars.length) + 1;
                }
                }while(t.contains(car) == false);
                int pick = r.nextInt(cars.length) + 1;


                break;

                }
}
}
};
```

`
expected unique cars randomized every time
results are randomized but not according to the user input

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Can you please edit your question and explain.  Also, you have an array of `colors` but don't use it.  And you have two `Sets` but only use one.  And don't close your scanner.

Comment: For example, if the user needs 4 cars painted the output only shows 2-3 randomly generated cars from the list instead of showing 4 randomized cars the user inputs the names of.

ex. if the user inputs 4 cars and names them "Honda" "Toyota" "Ford" and "Chevy"
The program will randomize the cars but will only output 2 or 3 cars from the list. It rarely outputs all 4 cars from the list in random order

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop there is a problem that you check `t.contains(car) == false` twice. If by accident you get a new unused value on the first iteration, you successfully add this value into `t`. But what would happen if you don't? You would continue getting other values (the else clause) until you get a value that is not present in `t`. Right after getting this value you exit the loop without adding the value into the container.

The solution:

```
do
{
    car = r.nextInt(cars.length) + 1;
}
while(t.contains(car));
t.add(car);
```

However there are other much more efficient solutions of your problem I'm just showing you the problem in your implementation.